# Get a returned value from a function in a function

Tags: php, function, return-value

I am currently learning PHP functions and I want to do the following.
Let's say I have two functions:

```
class baz{

  function foo(){  
    $string = "1234";  
    $string2 = $this -> bar($string);
    return $string2;
  }

  function bar($var){
    $var = $var . "abcd";
    return $var;
  }
}
```

I want to use the returned value from function bar in function foo.
To achieve this I declared a var inside the class and instead of returning the value I saved it into the var:

```
class baz{

  private baz;

  function foo(){  
    $string = "1234";  
    $this -> bar($string);
    $qux = $this -> baz;
    return $qux;
  }

  function bar($var){
    $var = $var . "abcd";
    $this -> baz = $var;
  }
}
```

Is it possible without using the var baz like my first try?

Comment: doesn't you'r first block of code work?

Comment: I do not really understand your problem.. you are assigning the return value of bar here: "$string2 = $this -> bar($string);", so you can do with $string2 whatever you want

Comment: Both are correct approach, but when you declare a variable like you did in 2nd case is usuful when the member variable is used across different methods. Say a typical case of login when you have a member variable to keep the iduser and its used accross different methods to find different information. But if its just used in one method then your first approach is a better one.

Comment: @fox You shouldn't edit your question according to the answers. This will create misunderstandings and make your question very hard to comprehend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Example:

```
class baz
  {
    private $baz;
    public function foo() 
      {
        $string = "1234";
        $baz    = $this->bar($string);
        return $baz;
      }
    public function bar($var) 
      {
        $newVar = $var . "abcd";
        return $newVar;
      }
  }

$a = new baz();
echo $a->foo(); // prints 1234abcd
```

[Example Online](http://ideone.com/2VS1I6)

When declaring `class` you must not use `()`;

As you said that you're learning functions and your example doesn't just contain functions. You could do it without creating an object, e.g.:

```
function foo() 
  {
    $string = "1234";
    $baz    = bar($string);
    return $baz;
  }
function bar($var) 
  {
    $newVar = $var . "abcd";
    return $newVar;
  }

echo foo(); // prints 1234abcd
```

[Example Online](http://ideone.com/SxITS4)